# Is there any way to make an - XML element value - dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I know that this question seems illogical, but I have to try, and I hope to find a way,

I've a DLL assembly reading a variable, "GalleryID", from an XML file. I can't modify the assembly, so I am wondering if I can make the XML element value dynamic? For example, to get this value from a querystring or any other scenario without changing the assembly.

In `Settings.xml`:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? >

< GallerySettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    < GalleryID >2< /GalleryID >   // Here I would like this value to be dynamic, not static like this.
< /GallerySettings >
```

In `mylibrary` assembly:

```
protected static XmlDocument myXmlDoc;
    ' in Page_Load ev mylibrary

    MyLibrary.myXmlDoc.Load(base.Server.MapPath("Conntrols/Settings.xml"));
    XmlNode documentElement = MyLibrary.myXmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    MyLibrary.myappSettings.GalleryID = documentElement.SelectSingleNode("GalleryID").ChildNodes[0].Value.ToString();
```

This is an ASP.NET website that has multiple users. When a user logs in and open the `gallery.aspx` page it will show the user's own gallery. This scenario is not working now since the gallery module shows one gallery (Galleryid=2) to all users according to its setting in `Settings.xml` file. How can I pass galleryid in querystring -- `gallery.aspx?galleryid=5`  and inject it to `Settings.xml` file?

Is that possible?

Comment: Is by any chance that `MyLibrary.myappSettings` a singleton? If so, then the value of GalleryID will always be the same for all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to restate what I understand from your question to make sure I 'get it'.

You have an assembly (from a .dll) that reads an XML file as a data source to  get the "GalleryID" out of a node that looks like: `<GalleryID>2</GalleryID>`

You want to be able to *change* the GalleryID *before* the assembly reads it.

I *assume* (yes, dangerous...) that you are invoking your assembly from an application that you DO have control over. (Since, presumably you don't have control over the assembly that reads the XML doc.)  This would be the calling context, and the host that defines exactly where the "Server" in Server.MapPath is going to look for `"Conntrols/Settings.xml"`

There are two basic solutions that come to mind:

1. Open the XML document, change the value and save it from your calling context.
2. Swap out XML document "settings.xml.alt" for "settings.xml" from your calling context.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, my problem is exactly as you described above but this is an ASP.net website have multi users, when the user log in and open gallery.aspx page it will show his own gallery this scenario is not working now since the gallery module shows one gallery to all users according to its setting in Settings.xml file , so what i am trying to do now is to pass galleryid in querystring -- gallery.aspx?galleryid=5  and find a way to inject it to Settings.XML file .

Comment: @Alaaddin, given this scenario I am unaware of a good method for injecting the desired value into your assembly without requiring it to be re-written to accommodate your goal. You obviously have a working knowledge of what is happening inside the assembly, what is the barrier to modifying it?

Comment: @cos-callis, I made this DLL since one year ago but i lost the latest copy of source code and now i want to use it again according to this new logic (GalleryID Dynamic not static)

Comment: @Alaaddin, I believe your best (perhaps 'only') option is the rework your assembly and chalk it up to a 'lesson learned' on why to **not** hard code values. _(and if you can't find the original, another lesson on the value of source control)_ I dare say that not a one of us out here hasn't learned a few lessons '_the hard way_'.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not be better off being done in an in-process database?

You are explaining to me that you are going to have a lot of different galleries. In this way, with that much dynamic data, I think you would be better to use an in-process database such as [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) and could be easily done using the [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) code. First, get the package off of [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet). If you have control over your data source I would personally go this route.